# GMail Calendar Event Attendees with Plus(+) in their email address

Tags: email, gmail-api

I am using the calendar event api to list events by an attendee's email address.  The api cannot find events if the attendee's email contains a plus "+".  The plus is supported by gmail for aliasing.  Is this a bug?

Example
https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22calendarId%22%3A%22some_email%40gmail.com%22%2C%22q%22%3A%22joe%2Bspam%40gmail.com%22%2C%22timeMax%22%3A%222022-02-23T21%3A00%3A00-00%3A00%22%2C%22timeMin%22%3A%222022-01-15T21%3A00%3A00-00%3A00%22%7D#try-it

Raw API call
/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendar_name}/events?timeMin=2022-02-05T21%3A00%3A00-08%3A00&timeMax=2022-02-13T21%3A00%3A00-08%3A00&singleEvents=true&orderBy=startTime&q=**joe%2Bspam%40gmail.com**

Create an GMail event and invite any email address containing a + (joe+spam@gmail.com).  Use Google's Try It Editor, https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list?apix=true#try-it, to try and find the event.